# hibernate path expected for join but path is set

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have an hql query:

```
"from User u inner join UserRole ur on ur.user_name = u.user_name and ur.user_role =ROLE_MANAGER "
```

And it shows an error though the path is set. I tried different variants of hql but error remains the same. I use those 2 entites for spring security login from db and it works fine. But when i'm trying to get user with specified role it doesn't work.
 My entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int user_id;


    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "passwort", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email = "hromnikforever@gmail.com";

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private int enabled = 1;

    @Autowired
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);
```

UserRole entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLES")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id",unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int user_role_id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "user_role")
    private String user_role;
```

If i change my HQL query to:

```
from User u inner join u.userRole ur on ur.user_name = u.user_name
and ur.user_role =ROLE_MANAGER "
```

it shows an error that

```
 could not resolve property: userRole of: com.webproject.User [from com.webproject.User u inner join u.userRole ur on ur.user_name = u.user_name and ur.user_role =ROLE_MANAGER ]
```

Comment: Can you paste the error trace

Comment: Your inner join part of your query is not correct. To get to UserRoles. You can do like ´from User u inner join u.userRoles ur´ Take a look at the hibernate documentation. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Comment: Why doesnt it work?  Give some details

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [from com.webproject.User u inner join UserRole ur on ur.user_name = u.user_name and ur.user_role =ROLE_MANAGER ]
this is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead explicit `JOIN` try with comma notation, and change the second `JOIN` table with `UserRole`, as follow:

```
from User u, UserRole ur
where ur.user_name = u.user_name
and ur.user_role = ROLE_MANAGER
```

If you want only User elements complete your query as follow:

```
select u from User u, UserRole ur
where ur.user_name = u.user_name
and ur.user_role = ROLE_MANAGER
```

Comment: It works now but what type will be list of List users = session.createQuery("this hql") ? how can i parse it?

Comment: If you want only user list, you must complete the query as follow: select u from ....

Comment: Man you just saved my life and at least a weak of working!

Comment: @Papich:Wow, have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your query, since your `User` entity doesn't have a `userRole`, but `userRoles`

```
from User u 
inner join u.userRoles ur on ur.user_name = u.user_name
                          and ur.user_role = ROLE_MANAGER
```